# timeshift restore stuck

Tags: grub2, timeshift

I'm new to linux and just broke my system.

machine: Lenovo thinkbook yoga 14s
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

I tried to clean my system with Bleachbit, it got stuck and filled up my drive, so I decided to go back with timeshift. I restored from a backup on my internal hard drive. During the restore it returned some error (I don't remember which) and seemed stuck. I hit the start button (probably a bad idea, I should have been more patient). Restarting it always just shows one line and is clearly stuck:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean 1754785/61022208 files, 242526850/244059136 blocks
```

I can boot into Grub, `ls`  shows

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

I managed to create and boot into a live usb version of ubuntu, install timeshift and restore (I tried both internal and external backup files). When I restart I just get the same line as before.

oh also tried booting into `(hd0,gpt2)` following https://linuxhint.com/grub_rescue_ubuntu_1804/ but it doesn't work, says it cannot find `/dev/sda2`

Short of reinstalling ubuntu and my entire system (which I would like to avoid) I am at my wit's end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally managed to start in recovery mode, delete the huge files that bleachbit made (https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html) and then everything suddenly worked normally again!

If you're a newbie like me, maybe do not mess with bleachbit ;)